# Layout selectors for JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx, vbox

I'm having difficulty understanding JavaFX CSS type selectors.
There doesn't seem to be a type-based selection like this:

```
VBox:first-child{
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

I am looking for a way to remove padding for only the first child of a VBox

Comment: Use specific selector for your first child ([id](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph)). Note in the JavaFX css, AFAIK there is no way to target a child from the parent.

Comment: as @Pagbo has already noted: _structural pseudo‑classes are not supported_, item 4 from [limitations section](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introlimitations)